# I tried '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic '; for bootstrap but still error which module should I include?

Tags: angular

I tried '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic ' for bootstrap but still error which module should I include ?

Comment: Please add more code that demonstrates what you have tried.

Comment: And the error message you get.